# Streaming video from a CDN to a flash player?

Tags: video, video-streaming, cdn

I was wondering if anyone had any experience with hosting video on a CDN and using it to stream to a flash player.

We want to use our existing flash player - JW Player - but stream from a CDN (Amazon possibly?).

Anyone done this before? What kind of statistics (requests, MB used etc) do you get for each video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash can be streamed from [Amazon's Cloud Front](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) service. The have a [detailed tutorial](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LiveStreamingAdobeFMS4.5.html) that can help you get up and running quickly.

Since it essentially works as a caching pass-through for Adobe's Flash Media Server (FMS), you get the same functionality, but with the benefit of CDN caching on an as-demanded basis.

They also have a [diagnostic client](http://d1k5ny0m6d4zlj.cloudfront.net/diag/CFStreamingDiag.html) to help you test things to make sure they work and help you figure out what is going wrong.